# Snowflake Python connector, connection.execute triggers two unknown SQL queries and two rollbacks call

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Two unknown SQL queries and a rollback call were executed every time when I ran connection.execute(SQL):
[image]

Two rollback calls were executed after my query.

Please see python code as follows:

```
try:
    time_start = pd.Timestamp.now()
    df = pd.read_sql_query(SQL, engine)
    time_end = pd.Timestamp.now()
    timer = pd.Timedelta(time_end-time_start).microseconds/1000
    print(timer)
except snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError as e:
    connection.rollback()
    print(e)
else:
    connection.commit()
finally:
    connection.close()
    engine.dispose()
    logging.debug('-------- Finished --------' )
    if to_csv:
        col_names = df.columns.tolist()
        if col_names_upper:
            col_names = [x.upper() for x in col_names]
        csv_file_name = 'data.csv'
        csv_path = os.path.join(dir_path,csv_file_name)
        if append:
            mode='a'
        else:
            mode='w'
        df.to_csv(csv_path,index=False, mode=mode, header=col_names)
        return None
    else:
        return df.to_dict()
```

When I checked the log file, I found those two queries were:

```
SELECT CAST('test unicode returns' AS VARCHAR(60)) AS anon_1
SELECT CAST('test unicode returns' AS VARCHAR(60)) AS anon_1
```

Why did this happen?

Comment: I've seen this too, but the rollback doesn't actually do anything in my experience.  I hope you find the answer, though.

Comment: Thank you Mike Walton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra queries you observe [come from the use of](https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00008eVdp4SAC/rollback-issue-in-snowflake-stored-procedure) the [sqlalchemy python library](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/).

As part of its initialization, the [sqlalchemy library runs a check](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py#L385-L417) to determine if unicode support, etc. is available in its runtime. They are harmless, internal checks that can be ignored.

Note: The SQL Alchemy project has, [as of 19th May 2020](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5315), [added a new change to skip this check](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/commit/af0e59ff16a2a02ec5dc1195212236e63fd941a7) if the runtime uses Python 3.x, so a future release version will not show these additional queries while using Python 3.x.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, do you happen to know the reasons behind those rollback calls?